# How to open a mat-expansion-panel by triggering an event?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to expand a mat-expansion-panel in angular material via a method call. For example I click on a button that then triggers an event to open the mat expansion panel. How should I do the same?

Answer (score 3):

There is an `expanded` [input](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api) property for `mat-expansion-pannel`, you may make use of that.

Your template:

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]='isExpanded'>
```

Your click action method of the button:

```
expand(){
this.isExpanded = !this.isExpanded;
}
```